# WooCommerce: get and echo "Order Total" on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I am trying to get the "Order Total" in a function with this code. But not working. The total is not printed at all.

What am I missing here?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' , 'add_in_order_review');
function add_in_order_review(){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order ) {
     $totalOrder = $order->get_formatted_order_total( );
     echo $totalOrder;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `$order_id` is not defined, so you cannot access the `$order` this way either. 
The object is also not yet created against the cart total

Comment: @7uc1f3r ok, how do I define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$order_id` is not defined, so you cannot access the `$order` this way either.
The `$order` object is also not yet created against the `$cart` object.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    echo 'CT = ' . $cart_total;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```

---

The orders that you can access are orders that have already been created in previous orders

Like:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
    // An order id from a previous order
    $order_id = 1966;
    
    // Get order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Is a WC order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        $total_order = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
        echo 'TO = ' . $total_order;
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```